# I just transmissions interchangeable?

Tags: transmission, dodge, avenger

I have a 2008 Dodge avenger SXT and a 2013 dodge avenger SE and I’m trying to find out if the transmissions will match to swap them out???… Or how exactly I would find out this information

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Which engines are used in each of the vehicles?

Comment: Doing some basic measurements of the number of bolts and length of the transmission would probably be a good first step.